# Missing disk space on SSD despite no paging file or hibernate.sys

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd, disk-space

I've been completely unable to find an answer as to why my SSD is missing ~20GB of space that doesn't include decreasing the size of the paging file, disabling hibernation or extending the volume in Disk Management. The problem is that I've done all of those things, and still there are so much space missing.

I've used up ~50GB when I right-click and select Properties on my system drive SSD, with all hidden files and folders shown, as well as the hidden protected operating system files(where the hibernate.sys and pagefile.sys would be, had I not disabled them)

I'm going crazy, all solutions on the web indicates the things I've already tried. Is it possible that the page file is still taking up space? I had it on c: before I moved it to another drive(and since then moved it back to c: and setting it to no paging file)

Any possible solution or something I haven't already tried would be much appreciated, right now I'm constantly forced to run CCleaner so my drive has at least ~100MB free.

Also, Space Sniffer sees the ~20GB of missing space as Unknown(not yet scanned) space.

Comment: Tried to clean System Restore?

Comment: Yes, they're all gone, and it's completely disabled as well

Comment: Tried Disk Cleanup as System?

Comment: Yes, it free'd up a whooping 710kb :/

Comment: Make sure you actually enabled the ability to see system files in Explorer (or use a command prompt), and see if you can find any out-of-place system files.

Comment: Ok, in C: .can you see $Recyle.Bin, System Volume Information (System restore stuff), and Recovery (Windows Refresh stuff)? By default no app could access their content (in turn, none can measure the size as well). It's possible the Recycle and System Volume Information is corrupted that clearing them from UI won't regain the space. Take over the ownership and grant yourself access, then try delete the contents (only delete Recovery if you have your Windows 8 DVD/USB installer)

Comment: Thanks, I checked all of that, they were almost empty, just a couple of hundreds of kb. I've already found the solution, I just can't accept my own answer for a while

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, so I found the answer after receiving a very useful link by Andrea de Palo, thank you!

After running SpaceSniffer in admin mode, after failing to see anything other than 'Unknown' when running WinDirStat in admin mode (goodbye WDS), I found what was taking up all my space (23.4GB to be exact). The C:/Windows/System32/config folder was full of .regtrans-ms and .blf files.

Apparently, according to [this page](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_you_delete_regtrans-ms_file) and [this page](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/blf), these files are both connected to the NTUser.dat, and possibly System Restore as well, but why they're never cleaned up I have no idea.

Anyhow, I deleted all of them, my computer is stable and I finally got a big portion of my 80GB SSD back!

Answer (score 0):

Have you ckecked your Temp directory? Sometimes files get piled up there, and neither Disk Cleanup or CCleaner delete them.

Write %temp% on your Start Menu searchbox (or go to c:\Users\«your username»\AppData\Local\Temp) and check how much space that folder is taking.

Also, what is the filesystem that your SSD is using? If it's FAT32 for some odd reason, and your SSD has 60GB of space, it might explain the missing space (FAT32 is limited to 32GB partitions)

Comment: ...don't both Disk Cleanup and CCleaner have options *specifically* for deleting temp files?

Comment: Yes, but CCleaner will only delete the files in your local folder after some time.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the temp directory, it currently contains 450kb. The operating system is Windows 8 and the filesystem is NTFS.

These are all good suggestions, but I think that Space Sniffer (or WinDirStat) would find these instead of marking them as unknown space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WinDirStat? You could use it to narrow down the culprit.

You should also check "system restore" disk settings

Comment: I suggest this as well!

Comment: Yes, WinDirStat also shows the space, 19.8GB as unknown.

The system restore points are deleted and System Restore is disabled for all disks

Comment: @ChrisNystrom - Post a screenshot

Comment: more info [here](http://blog.windirstat.info/20061013/unknown-space/comment-page-1/) on windirstat unknown file

Comment: I assume you mean a screenshot of WinDirStat?
[Screenshot](http://i49.tinypic.com/do1091.jpg).

Comment: I'm amazed at my stupidity! I didn't apparently run SpaceSniffer in admin mode, when I did I immediately discovered what was taking up all my space. For specifics note the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that the file system has been corrupted. You can try `chkdsk /f` (the command may be slightly different on Win8) to fix such corruption. **Warning: this operation may lead to data loss. Ensure you have up-to-date backups.**

Comment: Ran it, didn't help at all :/

Answer (score -1):

Make sure System Restore is reduced. In my case System Restore was currently configured to consume 50% of the storage space of the drive. To reconfigure, **[Right Click]Computer --> Properties --> System Protection** (on right) **--> Configure**.

Comment: The asker specifically states he has System Restore disabled.